# Puzzled: Clojure for loop with :while -> unexpected behaviour?

Tags: clojure

I've been learning Clojure and puzzled by the following:

```
user=> (for [a (range 1 4) b (range 1 4)] [a b])
([1 1] [1 2] [1 3] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [3 1] [3 2] [3 3]); _no surprise here_
```

Let's add `:while (not= a b)`, I expect to see an empty list as the loop should stop if the condition is false. In this case it's the very first item where `a`=`b`=1. Let's see:

```
user=> (for [a (range 1 4) b (range 1 4) :while (not= a b) ] [a b])

([2 1] [3 1] [3 2]) ; _surprise!_
```

Changing `:while` to `:when` to filter out `(= a b)` pairs

```
user=> (for [a (range 1 4) b (range 1 4) :when (not= a b) ] [a b])
([1 2] [1 3] [2 1] [2 3] [3 1] [3 2]); _expected_
```

Could anyone explain why `(for [ ... :while ..] ...)` behaves like this?

I'm using Clojure 1.3 on OS X.

Thank you and apologize for the lack of formatting. This is my virgin post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at each iteration.

```
a = 1
  b = 1 -> a == b, break because of while

a = 2
  b = 1 -> a != b, print [2 1]
  b = 2 -> a == b, break because of while

a = 3
  b = 1 -> a != b, print [3 1]
  b = 2 -> a != b, print [3 2]
  b = 3 -> a == b, break because of while
```

Comment: Thank you, Nikita. So if :while only applies to the inside loop, how do I make it apply to the outer loop as well? The problem I have is: (for [from [:a :b :c :d :e :f] to [:a :b :c :d :e :f] :let [path (find-path a b)] :while path) path); the loop should stop when path is nil.

Comment: Sorry, I meant
(for [from [:a :b :c :d :e :f] to [:a :b :c :d :e :f] :let [path (find-path from to)] :while path] path)

Comment: @jbear, I don't know :( May be you'd better create lazy seq of paths and take while they are not null. I'm not sure that `for` is lazy.

Answer (score 3):

The `:while` condition in `for` only terminates the inner-most loop. I use `for` all the time, but `:while` so rarely that I never realized this; thanks for the great question!

Sadly I think the best you can do is wrap a `take-while` around the `for`, since you want a "global" stop-counter on the output sequence, not a stop-counter on one of the input sequences you're iterating over. For example:

```
(->> (for [a (range 1 4)
           b (range 1 4)]
       [a b])
     (take-while (fn [[a b]] (not= a b))))

()
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `:while` test applies to the sequence immediately preceding it, not necessarily the inner-most loop.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Alex. Giving the prominence of the language, I couldn't help feeling a bit disappointed that one of the fundamental building blocks -- _list comprehension_ -- should turn out to be rather limiting. Hopefully as my learning progresses I'll discover more/better ways of doing it, with great help from everyone.

Comment: @jbear It's actually less limiting this way than it would be the other way. This way, you can easily wrap a `for` expression in a `take-while` if you want the "global" behavior. But if the "global" behavior were what `for/:while` did, how would you get back the current "intermediate" behavior? You'd have to abandon `for` entirely and build a rat's nest of map, mapcat, filter, take-while.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment. I hadn't considered the alternative behaviour.  Now it all makes perfect sense: I was my lack of understanding rather than an oversight of `for/:while` design.